# wire:ignore not working on component select2 and ckeditor

Tags: laravel-livewire

im using livewire 3.4 wire:ignore use to work but now it is not.
try with x-ignore still not working too.

```
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="form-label col-form-label required">
      State
    </label>
    <div wire:ignore>
      <select name="state_id" id="state_id"
        data-placeholder="select options"
        class="form-select form-select-solid form-select-lg" wire:model="state_id">
        @foreach ($states as $s)
          <option value="{{ $s->id }}">
            {{ $s->name }}
          </option>
        @endforeach
      </select>
    </div>

    @error('state_id')
      <p class="text-danger mt-5px mb-0">{{ $message }}</p>
    @enderror
  </div>
```

then submit data has been saved. element with ckeditor, select2 or map element was reload with not init script